# vue(axios) trust (or ignore) backend self signed certificate. ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: vue.js, ssl, self-signed-certificate

When front(axios) request to api server that secure with self signed certificate, I got `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` **error**.

If I write api in browser, it show not safe page(as we expect), after I trust that, vue can request to api without any problem.
how can i config vue to trust (or ignore) backend self signed certificate?

note: this is not work for me https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535#issuecomment-260841069

front: vue

backend: flask

Comment: You can simply install this certificate in your OS or in your browser (if it is Firefox and not Chrome) and from this moment it will become trusted for your PC.

Comment: the issue is not for me. its for clients

Comment: Then you should install a real certificate (e.g. from LetsEncrypt) and not a self-signed one!

Comment: how can resolved this issue whithout real certificate

Comment: Install your self-signed certificate in the `Trusted Root Certificates` group on each device of your customers.